# Many-particle systems where current and applied force are in opposite direction

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, non-equilibrium

Are there instances known (both observed or theoretic) of large-$N$ systems where applying an external force causes a current of the "corresponding charge" (present in the system) in the direction opposite of the applied force?

Note that the electric current in normal metals is not an answer to this question: although the average electron drift and applied electric field $E$ are opposite, the applied force $qE$ and average electron drift share the same direction.

Comment: I don't believe there are any 'simple' systems (homogenous simple geometry like a sphere, etc.) like that, but I can imagine a more complex (yet still passive) structure in which a portion of it experiences what you describe. More specifically, in one part of the structure  electrons move away, and that movement causes other electrons to move toward the external force in another part. However, I don't believe one would ever have a *net* movement toward the external force unless the system were active (i.e. nonlinear, amplification, etc.).